# React image on my webpage is not responding to the css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, styling

for some reason my class "hidden-Mouseketeer" not reading from my CSS file correctly. It is an image that has swing animation into it and will swing side to side. (Nor will the image center). the rest of the page is reading from the css file fine.

For some reason if I add a space to the end of the class name and save it, it'll sort of jump starts the css. It'll read fine after refreshing the page. But shortly afterwards it'll stop rendering how id like it and the image will be full blown.

this is the React section, with the included imports

```
import HM from "../img/HiddenMouseketeer.png";
import "../style/App.css";

    <Container fluid>
      <Container class="mx-auto">
         <Image src={HM} class="hidden-Mouseketeer" alt="Hidden Mouseketeer" />
      </Container>
    </Container>
```

here is the CSS styling section

```
.hidden-Mouseketeer{
  width: 20%;
  animation: swing 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes swing {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25%{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75%{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Hidden Mouseketeer]

Comment: In react, you have to use `className` instead of `class`. And please do console and post screenshot

Answer (score 1):

With React components you need to use className instead of class.

Comment: LOL such a small mistake, thanks for the catch on that!!